# Mongoose updateMany not updating records using an array as filter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node application using MongoDB 7.0.5 Community, Mongoose 7.6.8, MongoDB drivers 6.3.0 and Node version 20.10.0.

I can't get this code to work:

```
const updatedDealer = await my_model.updateMany(
  {
    CustomerId: 123,
    'Vehicles.Id': { $in: IdArray }
  },
  {
    $set: { 'Vehicles.$.FieldsToUpdate': true }
  },
  {
    multi: true
  }
);
```

IdArray is literally an array of numbers. My Mongoose model is correct, because if I update a single record using:

```
const updatedDealer = await my_model.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
     CustomerId: 123,
     'Vehicles.Id': 123456
  },
  {
    $set: { 'Vehicles.$.FieldsToUpdate': true }
  },
  {
    new: true 
  }
);
```

It works.
Nether CustomerId or Vehicles.Id are MongoDB _ids.

This is a simplified example of my data:

```
[{
CustomerId: 123,
CustomerName: 'Some Company',
Vehicles: [
    {
        Id: 123456,
        Make: 'Ford',
        Model: 'Focus',
        FieldsToUpdate: false
    },
    {
        Id: 543213,
        Make: 'Kia',
        Model: 'EV9',
        FieldsToUpdate: false
    }
]
}]
```

And a simplified example of my model:

```
const my_model = mongoose.Schema({
CustomerId: {
    type: Number
},
CustomerName: {
    type: String
},
Vehicles: [
    {
        Id: {
            type: Number
        },
        Make: {
            type: String
        },
        Model: {
            type: String
        },
        FieldsToUpdate: {
            type: Boolean
        }
    }
]
})
```

Would appreciate any help with this one. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a sample document please?

Comment: That’s a bit problematic as it’s customers data. But I’ve updated the original post to show simplified version of the data and model.

Comment: Does that code throw an error, not update anything, or update the wrong element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose V7 doesn't have a `Model.update()` method, it was [removed in V7](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_7.html#removed-update).

You can use `Model.updateMany()` as follows:

```js
const updatedDealer = await my_model.updateMany({
        CustomerId: 123,
        "Vehicles.Id": { $in: IdArray }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "Vehicles.$[var].FieldsToUpdate": true
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {
                "var.Id": {
                    $in: IdArray
                }
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

This uses the [filtered positional operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) `$[<identifier>]` in the `$set` stage by inserting the variable name `[var]` in the position of the element so that it can be used in the `arrayFilters` to identify that array element and only update when the `$in` condition is met.

Answer (score 2):

you could use an arrayFilter to update the subdocuments you want.

```
db.collection.update({
  CustomerId: 123,
  "Vehicles.Id": {
    $in: IdArray
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "Vehicles.$[x].FieldsToUpdate": true
  }
},
{
  "multi": true,
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "x.Id": {
        $in: IdArray
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

See on [mongoplayground.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PXoxDASQpu1)

Comment: why is the array filter needed https://mongoplayground.net/p/pFz08hX44z3

Comment: To update all subdocuments, without arrayFilter it only update the first subdocument : https://mongoplayground.net/p/bx4L_hU9xSN (here Kia is updated but not Kia2)

Comment: While this answer will do the update, the OP is on Mongoose v7 so cannot use the `update` method as it was removed in V7. They need to use `updateMany`.